# Using grep in if statements in perl

Tags: perl

I have multiple log files that looks like dmesg output. I need to parse and store certain result from all these files into one single output file. 
Ex Input file1:

```
 .....
 Started 1399343129
 KbPerSec  1222
 KiloBytes 9302938
 Status 83
 StorageUNit unitname
 Ended 1399473434
 .......
```

Output file:

```
  1399343129  1222  9302938 83 unitname 1399473434
  <input file2 numbers>
  <input file3 numbers>
  .....
```

So, I use grep, and split the grep result to get the number I want. Here is what my code looks like.
`<TRY>` is my file handle.

```
my (@grepres, @splitres);
my ($size, $start, $bw);

if(@grepres=grep{/KbPerSec/} <TRY>){
  @splitres=split(' ',$grepres[0]);
  $bw=$splitres[1];
  print "1. $bw\n";
}

if(@grepres=grep{/Started/} <TRY>){
  @splitres=split(' ',$grepres[0]);
  $start=$splitres[1];
  print "$start\n";
}

...
```

1. But my code only executes the first if, and then stops. Why does it not execute the other if statements?
2. This doesnt seem like an efficient way to do this. How can I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because `<TRY>` in list context consumes all the data in the `TRY` filehandle, making subsequent calls to `<TRY>` return empty. If you want to reuse the data in the filestream, either

a. save the stream to a variable

```
 my @try = <TRY>;
 if ( grep ..., @try ) {
    ...
 }
 if ( grep ..., @try ) { 
    ...
 }
```

b. reopen the file or `seek` back to the beginning

```
 open TRY, '<', $try_file
 ...
 if (grep ..., <TRY>) {
    ...
 }
 close TRY;
 open TRY, '<', $try_file
 if (grep ..., <TRY>) {
    ...
 }

 open TRY, '<', $try_file
 ...
 if (grep ..., <TRY>) {
    ...
 }

 seek TRY, 0, 0;  # reset cursor position to start of file

 if (grep ..., <TRY>) {
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach that depends on the fields being in the same order from record to record.

**Update:** Changed the end condition match.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^Started/ .. /^Ended/) {
        push @data, /^\S+ (.+)$/;
        print join(" ", splice @data), "\n" if /^Ended/;    
    }
}

__DATA__
.....
Started 1399343129
KbPerSec  1222
KiloBytes 9302938
Status 83
StorageUNit unitname
Ended 1399473434
.......
```

Prints

```
1399343129  1222 9302938 83 unitname 1399473434
```

Comment: if you do that, declare `$end` before the while loop, not in the assignment.  otherwise you are subject to the undefined behaviour mentioned in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html where it says "Here be dragons."

Comment: @ysth Thank you for noticing - I made your suggested change.